# Using regex to match a specific pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to match any strings that doesn't start with "false1" or "false2", and ends with true, but the regex isn't matching for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
$text = "start true";
$regex = "~(?:(^false1|false2).+?) true~";
if (preg_match($regex, $text, $match)) {

echo "true";    

}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
true
```

**Actual Result:**

```
null
```

Comment: Throw your regex into: https://regex101.com and look at the explanation to the right. Then you will see what your regex really does. (`^(?<!false1|false2)(.*?)true$`)

Comment: @Rizier123 Is that regex in your comment a solution or...? Because it doesn't match correctly.

Comment: @Rizier123 Also, I already know about that website, and knowing what it does, doesn't help me figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @Rizier123 Well, I assume you didn't trying matching with starting of "false1" and "false2"? Because it echos there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use negative lookahead.

```
^(?!false[12]).*true$
```

If you really want to use boundaries then try this,

```
^(?!false[12]\b).*\btrue$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cC4xP4/1)

Update:

```
^(?!.*false[12]\b).*\btrue$
```

`(?!.*false[12]\b)` negative lookahead which asserts that the string would contain any char but not the sub-string `false1` or `false2` and it must ends with the string `true`, that's why we added `true$` at the last.

Comment: But if the $text is something like "start false1 true", it also echos.

Comment: `I'm trying to match any strings that doesn't start with "false1" or "false2"` . But the above does'nt starts with false1.

Comment: I don't want it to match ANY string that has false1, or false2 followed by true. Sorry if I wasn't really clear with that.

Comment: try `^(?!.*false[12]\b).*\btrue$`

Comment: It works. But it's a really complex regex, and there's some part that I don't understand. Can you break it down, and explain it in the answer above, please? Thanks.

Comment: Great answer! Okay, I have to ask. Which chapter in which book did you read to get you 107K rep in regex?

Comment: just mentione that regex is a common thing which belongs to all major languages. I learned all the regex stuffs from this site only, but viewing and asking doubts regarding the regex answers posted by  seniors.